# Jersey integrated quartz @Inject annotation not working

Tags: quartz-scheduler, jersey-2.0

The specific reason I know is because the QuartzJob class is instantiated, but I know that the constructor with no arguments is used, and then the `execute` method is called to report the exception. `@Inject` does not work.

Printed error message：

```
org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openscoring.service.quartz.QuartzJob.execute(QuartzJob.java:36)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
... 1 more
```

QuartzJob implements the Job interface

```
@Service
@Singleton
public class QuartzJob implements Job {

    @Inject
    private SynchronousCache synchronousCache;

        @Override
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext content)  {
            System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())+ "★★★★★★★★★★★");

            synchronousCache.synchronizationModel();

        }


}



QuartzManager.addJob("test", QuartzJob.class, "10/59 * * * * ? *");
```

Add a timed task

Comment: Yes, of course. The previous code is fine. This time, the QuartzJob class is accessed through the QuartzJob.class form, so it seems that the no-argument constructor is called only by reflection, only excute() is executed, and the instance variable is not initialized. As long as it runs, it is wrong.

Comment: I don't see why the job would be going through the DI system at all. Quartz is the one that creates the job object, not HK2. If someone else is creating the job, then it is not going through the HK2 DI system, which it would need to be in order for the DI to work.